# CakePHP 3 associates between two tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create associations between two Models ( servers and application_endpoints) tables in cakephp 3. What I would like to achieve is to get all the data from application_endpoints table to servers model. So in the view i can access all the data.

Server can have multiple VIPs and endpoints in application_endpoints table and I am using hasMany association. So in ServersTable.php I added below code:

```
$this->hasMany('ApplicationEndpoints', [
            'foreignKey' => 'server_id',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
```

So when I browse server view page and click on debug kit inside variable tab, I dont see any joins. I see list of servers in array, but each server in array doesnt show any relationships to application_endpoints table.

Please comment and let me know if it is not clear, I am also linking [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e5c7) about mysql schema.

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried this code as well in ServersTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('ApplicationEndpoints', [
            'bindingKey' => 'server_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So hasMay is the right way to make association between two models.

```
    $this->hasMany('ApplicationEndpoints', [
        'foreignKey' => 'server_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ]);
```

I had to add extra code in controller of server to make it work with below code:

```
    // View method
    $query = $this->Servers->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ApplicationEndpoints']
    ]);
    $this->set('data', $query);
```